# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

The classic repeat over and over question about wcf....
I've been through dozens of stack questions looking for my fix to no avail...

This is in Elastic Beanstalk IIS 10

The Error

```
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/SynoviaApi.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   at
```

here is my config.

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="7200" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Synovia.Api.SynoviaApi">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISynoviaApiService" contract="Synovia.Api.ISynoviaApi" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
     </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- set httpGetEnabled="false" if https -->
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISynoviaApiService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <!-- set mode="Transport" if https -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you using Visual studio's web server (which doesn't work with SSL) or IIS Express?

Comment: This is in Elastic Beanstalk IIS 10